# Does epoll preserve the order in which fd's was registered?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I'm playing around with Linux system call and I found some aspect of `epoll`, that is not clear to me. Say, I create a `epoll` instance:

```
epollfd = epoll_create(50);
```

Next, I register 50 file descriptors in `for`-loop:

```
for(i=0; i<50; i++){
    // open file "file-i".txt
    // construct epoll_event
    // register new file descriptor with epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD ...
```

Now we have 50 file, that are ready for action(read or write -- doesn't matter). We set MAX_EVENTS to 3:

```
#define MAX_EVENTS 3
...
struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS]
...
epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1)
```

All of those 50 files were ready, we asked only for 3 of them. Which files will be in `events` array?

- [1,2,3] -- first 3 files in order they were added to epoll
- [48,49,50] -- last 3 files in order they were added to epoll
- [34, 7, 15] -- random 3 files
- any other option

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perusing through the source file for [`epoll`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/fs/eventpoll.c), one sees that the ready events are maintained in a linked list. Events are removed from the head of the list and added to the end of the list.

Based on that, the answer is that the descriptor order is based on the order in which they became ready.

This behavior is now documented in the notes for [`epoll_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html):

> If more than `maxevents` file descriptors are ready when `epoll_wait()`
>          is called, then successive `epoll_wait()` calls will round robin
>          through the set of ready file descriptors.  ...

The documentation is thanks to [@mtk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984186/315052) .

Comment: I'd also like to add that an mtx lock is held on each CPU so if you have a situation where fd's became available simultaneously on an MP machine, it would be whoever won the lock.

Comment: @jxh, so in my case, if I add 50 file descriptors that are ready to read/write, I'll get [1,2,3] with epoll_wait. Right?

Comment: @amezhenin not necessarily ... you have no guarantee that your read/write took place in a serial order. you'll get the first three descripters of the 50 that became ready for read/write

Comment: @amezhenin: If all the descriptors were already ready before you added them, and you are not using edge triggered behavior, then I would expect you get the descriptors in the order that you added them. With edge triggered behavior, I would expect you would not get back any descriptors, but I would need to test that out, because it is a boundary condition, and `poll` may make a special case for when the descriptor is added.